# Why don't my settings and single player progress get saved?

Tags: origin, battlefield-1

I hoped this would be fixed soon. Unfortunately I still got this problem:

Sometimes when I start Battlefield 1 from Origin it runs right into the first-launch-setting-screen. There where you can set your gamma and audio device settings. After doing so it just continued with the intro instead of loading to main menu.

First I thought this issue has to do with Origin cloud-sync (I encountered problems with that earlier in other games). However, this issue comes up both ways (cloud-sync enabled / disabled).

I already reinstalled Battlefield 1 and Origin but that didn't help.

If you got any hint to this issue or if you got the same problem, please share your experiences. I would really appreciate your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue a few weeks ago. I had to reinstall the Origin client and Battlefield 1. I also disabled cloud-sync for this game. After all it's working fine and I think the issue got fixed during latest patches.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess this issue got fixed during the latest updates. Now it's working fine. My story progress gets saved and also my basic settings remain after restarting the game.

By the way, I think Origin cloud-sync was involved causing the issue. I turned it off, just to make sure it doesn't mess around.